# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema con expresiones regulares en golang?

Tags: regex, go

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy teniendo un problema en golang que no se como resolver, estoy usando expresiones regulares para analizar el contenido de un archivo, y estoy buscando el patron `"{{ ... }}"` (donde puse `"..."` va cualquier valor, solo busco `"{{"`, `"}}"`, y el contenido dentro de las llaves) Lo que quiero hacer con este patron es tener todos los resultados que hayan en una linea, si solo hay una coincidencia no hay problema y funciona como espero, pero lo malo es cuando hay mas de una coincidencia. Ejemplo, si uso este texto:

```
Lorem ipsum {{ texto1 }} dolor sit amet, consectetur {{ texto2 }} adipiscing elit
```

Lo que me gustaria hacer es tener como resultado que me devuelva lo que esta dentro de `texto1` y lo que esta dentro de `texto2` pero por separado, pero en su lugar lo que hace es que me devuelve todo lo que esta desde `texto1` **hasta** `texto2` y no **dentro** de, por lo que de resultado tengo:

```
{{ texto1 }} dolor sit amet, consectetur {{ texto2 }}
```

Y no:

```
{{ texto1 }},  {{ texto2 }}
```

Ahora que he intentado explicar lo que quiero hacer, aqui esta mi codigo:

```
package main

import (
  "regexp"
  "log"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("{{.*}}")

    buscar := re.FindAllStringSubmatch("Lorem ipsum {{ texto1 }} dolor sit amet, consectetur {{ texto2 }} adipiscing elit", -1)

    log.Print(validLine)

}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar y espero haberme explicado bien, desde ya gracias :).

Comment: Te hace falta hacerlo "no codicioso" (`non-greedy`) agregando un signo de interrogación, de esta forma `{{.*?}}` pero si te quisieras únicamente lo que está dentro de las llaves entonces debes usar paréntesis `{{(.*?)}}`

Comment: @HeytalePazguato muchas gracias, lo hice como dijiste y ya funcionó, no se si gustas ponerlo como respuesta para  marcar que mi pregunta ya tiene solución

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buen día,

Al trabajar con `regex` hay una función llamada "codicioso" (En inglés `greedy`) que en caso de haber múltiples coincidencias lo que hace es tomar todo lo que haya desde la primera coincidencia hasta la última.

En tu caso lo que hay que hacer es hacerlo "no codicioso" o también llamado "perezoso" (En inglés `non-greedy`) para que busque cada grupo por separado. Para eso utilizamos el signo de interrogación `?`.

Hay una página que yo utilizo para probar los `regex` que es múy útil ya que a la derecha te explica como funciona lo que estás haciendo, se llama [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/).

### Conclusión:

Para poder obtener únicamente los grupos puedes utilizar el siguiente `regex`:

```
{{.*?}}
```

Si quisieras obtener únicamente lo que está adentro de las llaves entonces hay que agregar paréntesis:

```
{{(.*?)}}
```